# A subfactor of finite index

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

We say $N$ is a subfactor of finite index of the factor $M$ if there is a normal faithful conditional expectation of $M$ onto $N$ that has finite index.

If $N$ is a subfactor of finite index of the factor $M$, can we deduce that $M$ and $N$ have the same type?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is a special case of the results in Section 2 of Frank and Kirchberg's article "On conditional expectations of finite index" [arXiv:math/9804074].

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I have another question :  If $N$ and $M$  has the same type and there exist a normal faithful conditional expectation $E$ from $M$ onto $N$, under what condition we have  the index of $E$ is finite?